# Round robin scheduling

Tags: php

I need help on round robin scheduling. I have appointment,company,users.

e.g. 2 users in 1 company

```
Appointment 1 user 1 company 1
appointment 2 user 2 company 1
appointment 3 user 1 company 1
appointment 4 user 2 company 1.
```

Use php script. I am stuck. Anyone one have any suggestion. Please help!

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you rephrase?

Comment: Are you using a Database? Are you trying to prevent conflicts? are you trying to order a list of people such that the list evenly spaces out the people, or perhaps appointments?

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to implement basic round robin, not sure this is what you ment as the commenters have said you're little vague:

```
<?php

  $appointments = array();
  $users = array('Jon', 'Billy', 'George', 'Michael');

  for ($i = 0, $max=count($users); $i < $max; $i++) {
    for($j = $i+1; $j < $max; $j++) {
      $appointments[] = array($users[$i], $users[$j]);
    }
  }

  print_r($appointments);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the Cartesian product of users, companies.

```
function getAppts($users, $companies)
{
    $appts = array();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        foreach ($companies as $company) {
            $appts[] = array($user, $company);
        }
    }
    return $appts;
}

$appts = getAppts(array('user1', 'user2'), array('company1'));
```

This will produce the combinations you need:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => user1
            [1] => company1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => user2
            [1] => company1
        )

)
```

The function allows you to add more users or companies and get all the appointment combinations. You can then foreach through `$appts` and building your queries.